# Match phone numbers with names in Excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7JA.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT6w1.png)

This is a phone book in Excel. I have this type of Excel sheet. This page has 2000 lines. When I write the number, column B if there is a number in this table, (check column B) it will automatically write its name in the column A.

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| name | phone number |
| john SMITH | 222 222 22 22 |
| alice JOHNSON | 333 333 33 33 |
| sam BROWN | 444 444 44 44 |
| john WHITE | 555 555 55 55 |
| tim WALKER | 666 666 66 66 |
| **** | 444 444 44 44 |

When I write here 444 444 44 44 it will automatically write its name in the column A sam   BROWN.(****)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using INDEX/MATCH/INDEX:

[image]

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,INDEX((SUBSTITUTE($B$8," ","")=SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6," ",""))*1,0,1),0)),"Not Found")
```

Doing it this way allows you to use SUBSTITUTE to do the comparison without spaces.

So that 4444444444 will still return "sam BROWN".

***EDIT***

Adding the formula for those that have semi-colons set as the default list separator in their regional settings (instead of commas):

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$6;MATCH(1;INDEX((SUBSTITUTE($B$8;" ";"")=SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6;" ";""))*1;0;1);0));"Not Found")
```

Comment: =IFNA(INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(1,INDEX((SUBSTITUTE(B8," ","")=SUBSTITUTE(B2:B6," ",""))*1,0,1),0)),"Not Found") when i copy this function nothing happens. like

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "nothing happens". Is your data in the same locations as in my example?

Comment: Also, if your excel is not set up to use comma's you may need to replace them with your own symbols (semi-colons? ; )

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/cjgl5sq yes same

this is my file 
https://dosya.co/3q6vb5b3rrja/11.xlsx.html

Comment: No... it's not the same. You have a circular reference because you have put the formula in A6 instead of A8. Move the formula to A8. Delete the space at the start before the "=", which is making excel treat it as text rather than a formula. Then enter a matching number in B8. It should work then.

Comment: i moved a8 to a6
= is okey but now there is another error
https://www.hizliresim.com/t43o2zz

thanks for helping

Comment: It looks like you have semi-colons `;` set as your default list separator in your regional settings (instead of commas `,`). Try this: `=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$6;MATCH(1;INDEX((SUBSTITUTE($B$8;" ";"")=SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6;" ";""))*1;0;1),0));"Not Found")`

Comment: Sorry... missed the second to last comma: `=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$6;MATCH(1;INDEX((SUBSTITUTE($B$8;" ";"")=SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6;" ";""))*1;0;1);0));"Not Found")`

Comment: there is no error but funtion is not run :(
https://www.hizliresim.com/jkj249b

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? `#NAME?` means that you don't have access to one or more of the functions (probably `IFNA`). Try `=INDEX($A$2:$A$6;MATCH(1;INDEX((SUBSTITUTE($B$8;" ";"")=SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6;" ";""))*1;0;1);0))`  if that works, you can then handle the `#N/A` errors with a simple `IF`.

Comment: excel for mac 2011 v14.0.0 (100825)

you are perfect thank you very much you are amazing you are great. 
the formula worked

Comment: Ah. I don't have any experience with macs so I am not sure how that version differs. But I am glad it's working for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Xlookup will do the trick, assume that you write the number in for example D12 (can be changed to where ever you will type in the number). Using B1:B1000 as input for the numbers and A1:A1000 as input for the names (these can also be changed or even better, use named ranges) `=XLOOKUP(D12;B1:B1000;A1:A1000;"not found";0;1)`